# PHP Array, get the key based on a value

Tags: php

If I have this array

```
$england = array(
        'AVN' => 'Avon',
        'BDF' => 'Bedfordshire',
        'BRK' => 'Berkshire',
        'BKM' => 'Buckinghamshire',
        'CAM' => 'Cambridgeshire',
        'CHS' => 'Cheshire'
);
```

I want to be able to get the three letter code from the full text version, how would i write the following function:

```
$text_input = 'Cambridgeshire';
function get_area_code($text_input){
    //cross reference array here
    //fish out the KEY, in this case 'CAM'
    return $area_code;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search):

```
$key = array_search($value, $array);
```

So, in your code:

```
// returns the key or false if the value hasn't been found.
function get_area_code($text_input) {
    global $england;
    return array_search($england, $text_input);
}
```

If you want it case insensitive, you can use this function instead of `array_search()`:

```
function array_isearch($haystack, $needle) {
   foreach($haystack as $key => $val) {
       if(strcasecmp($val, $needle) === 0) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

If you array values are regular expressions, you can use this function:

```
function array_pcresearch($haystack, $needle) {
   foreach($haystack as $key => $val) {
       if(preg_match($val, $needle)) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

In this case you have to ensure all values in your array are valid regular expressions.

However, if the values are coming from an `<input type="select">`, there's a better solution:
Instead of `<option>Cheshire</option>` use `<option value="CHS">Cheshire</option>`. Then the form will submit the specified value instead of the displayed name and you won't have to do any searching in your array; you'll just have to check for `isset($england[$text_input])` to ensure a valid code has been sent.

Comment: +1 @Haroldo be aware that array_search is case sensitive when working with strings.

Comment: Is it possible to do array_seach, where the value is a regular expression? Then i could use preg_quote and account for abbreviations and different versions of and...

Comment: @Thief  - excellent advice on using the select input, thanks!

Comment: Importing the haystack with `global` is a bad idea. It should be passed to the function as parameter. Then the function would be just an alias of array_search and you should use array_search directly.

Comment: @Haroldo: Added a regex example to my answer.
@rik: Indeed. Global variables are bad, especially for stuff like that.

Comment: @Thief: one of the most comprehensive answers i've ever received, thanks again

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I've just modified the order of the arguments you listed for array_search, as the documentation states $needle should be 1st and $haystack 2nd.

Answer (score 6):

If all values in `$england` are unique, you can do:

```
$search = array_flip($england);
$area_code = $search['Cambridgeshire'];
```

Comment: That code creates a new array which is certainly less efficient than iteratinv over an existing one. However, it is better than array_search etc. you have to lookup many values as array key->value lookups most likely use a hash map while value->key lookups require iteration.